# Why are both of these MSSQL indexes useful?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a MSSQL database table `Events`. I am worried that performance could be improved.

| EventId | LocationId | Start | End | Quantity | Price | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2022-08-31 22:00:00.0000000 +02:00 | 2022-08-31 23:00:00.0000000 +02:00 | 7.50000 | 2.0 | EUR |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-04-04 19:00:00.0000000 +01:00 | 2022-04-04 20:00:00.0000000 +01:00 | 1.50000 | 7.5 | EUR |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-04-04 19:00:00.0000000 +01:00 | 2022-04-04 20:00:00.0000000 +01:00 | 4.00000 | 8.2 | EUR |

I already have the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX__Events__Location_Start_End] on [Events]
(
    [LocationId] asc,
    [Start] asc,
    [End] asc
)
```

But Azure suggests that I create this index (medium impact):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX__Events__Location_End] ON [dbo].[Events] ([LocationId], [End]) INCLUDE ([Currency], [Price], [Quantity], [Start]) WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

Hint: I do a lot of queries where I select Events greater than a start time and less than an end time.

Why is this extra index useful? Should I change my first index instead?

**EDIT**:

I run this code (EF Core) very often:

```
var relevantEvents = await _events.Where($@"
    [{nameof(Events.LocationId)}] = @locationId 
        and [{nameof(Events.End)}] > @start 
        and [{nameof(Events.Start)}] < @end

", args);
```

Besides that, I upsert to the table often as well.

Comment: Without the queries, we can't comment on why they are useful to the RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always do queries of the form shown at the end of your question with an equality predicate on `LocationId` and an inequality predicate on both `End` and `Start` then both `LocationId, End` and `LocationId, Start` would be viable indexing choices.

Note there is no benefit of adding the third column in as a `key` column because it will only be able to do a range seek for one or the other of them but the other one should be added as an included column.

My suspicion is that for typical scenarios `LocationId, Start` will generally involve reading more rows in the range seek than `LocationId, End` would (as the table accumulates years worth of data `Start < @end` will still need to read all the old rows from years ago).

The reason your existing index might not be being used and it feels moved to suggest an additional one is due to the `INCLUDE ([Currency], [Price], [Quantity])` in the suggested one. If you add these included columns to your existing one you may well see the recommendation go away but you should consider which of `LocationId, End` and `LocationId, Start` will typically be able to narrow down the rows better (see "Numbers of rows read" in the execution plan).

---

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events
(
EventId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
LocationId INT, 
Start DATETIME2,
[End] DATETIME2,
Quantity DECIMAL(10,6),
Price DECIMAL(10,2),
Currency CHAR(3),
INDEX IDX__Events__Location_Start_End(LocationId, Start, [End]),
INDEX IDX__Events__Location_End(LocationId, [End]) INCLUDE (Start)
)


INSERT INTO dbo.Events
(LocationId, Start,[End], Quantity, Price,Currency)
SELECT LocationId = 1,
       Start = DATEADD(SECOND, -Num, GETDATE()),
       [End] = DATEADD(SECOND, 60-Num, GETDATE()),
       Qty = 7.5,
       Price = 2,
       Currency = 'EUR'
FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 1000000 Num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
FROM sys.all_columns c1, sys.all_columns c2
) Nums


DECLARE @Start DATE = GETDATE(), @End DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Events WITH (INDEX = IDX__Events__Location_Start_End)
WHERE LocationId = 1 AND [End] > @Start AND Start < @End
OPTION (RECOMPILE)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Events WITH (INDEX = IDX__Events__Location_End)
WHERE LocationId = 1 AND [End] > @Start AND Start < @End
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```